# When all else fails, return to me for a few moments respite

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Heaven to some, sanctuary for others,
> Ease is to come, unless at anothers.
>
> A few minutes, a few hours, take all you need.
> Virtually all rest is ours, for me you'll plead.
>
> Even those who try to escape me will succumb,
> Now don't run from me, or a monster you will become.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you a

> Bed or sleep?

Heaven to some, sanctuary for others,

> Some people enjoy sleep because they enjoy it, others need their sleep

Ease is to come, unless at anothers.

> Sleeping over might take some work, setting up beds or napping on their couch which is weird

A few minutes, a few hours, take all you need.

> Power naps or full on sleeping

Virtually all rest is ours, for me you'll plead.

> You’ll plead to sleep or to have a bed to sleep on

Even those who try to escape me will succumb,

> People who try to escape sleeping eventually need to sleep

Now don't run from me, or a monster you will become.

> And you become angry and tired if you avoid sleeping

Comment: That is correct. Something I always look forward to.

Comment: And something I always want more of too! I hear you, @Joe-You-Know